# Specify order of headers in NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, http-headers, nsurlrequest

How do I specify the order of the HTTP header fields in an `NSMutableURLRequest`?

I have tested `setAllHTTPHeaderFields` and `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`, but when looking at the request using [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) the order is messed up.

**Edit**

Why all this? I want the requests sent from iOS to be completely indistinguishable with requests sent from other clients, which I cannot modify.

Comment: Why is the order important? If the order is important to the server, why doesn't it do the ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allHTTPHeaderFields` is an NSDictionary, which is, by its nature, an unordered collection. Also, the HTTP specification/RFC states that ordering of headers doesn't matter: See [RFC 2616, section 4.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html):

> The order in which header fields with differing field names are
>   received is not significant. However, it is "good practice" to send
>   general-header fields first, followed by request-header or response-
>   header fields, and ending with the entity-header fields.

So I'm gonna go with "No, it's not possible to specify the order."